# Python SyntaxError when formatting

Tags: python

```
print "Detections before NMS = {}".format(detections)
```

Produces:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: 1) Don't add "it's urgent". People here are volunteers so your deadlines are not relevant. 2) We can't tell what is causing this error from what you have provided. You need to give more information/show more code

Comment: And you might want to start using `print("text")` instead of `print "text"`if you are using 2.7 - because the latter will fail in 3.x

Answer (score 1):

```
detections = 10

print ("Detections before NMS = {}".format(detections))
```

Output:

```
Detections before NMS = 10
```

If you are using Python 3, `print` is a function and therefore needs brackets.

I suspect you are on Python 3, hence the syntax error.